# Only show the Opportunity with the highest probability per Account in Report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, filters

Tried to summarize the probability field to 'Max' but it still shows all the opps under the account (+ the one with the highest one)

I am using a standard 'opportunity' report - I do not want to create custom formulas or rollups for this but just use pre-built functionality

**I just want to see the opp with the highest %** --- NOT all of them!

How do I achieve this?